# Is it possible to rename the folder 'VAADIN' inside 'webapps' in a vaadin application?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I want to rename the folder 'VAADIN' inside the vaadin webapps folder.
When a vaadin application user rightclick the page and view page-source there it shows this folder name.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/mytheme/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="./VAADIN/themes/mytheme/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js?v=7.7.0"></script>
```

How can i rename that folder name to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer from vaadin forum. 
https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/14109320

just don't do it.

Of course it can be done, and because Vaadin is all Open Source, yes it can be done.
./server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/Constants.java:136:    final String THEME_DIR_PATH = "VAADIN/themes";
./server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/Constants.java:140:    static final String WIDGETSET_DIR_PATH = "VAADIN/widgetsets";
are places where you'd go first but since Vaadin Framework has grown over many years and we don't live in a perfect world, there are other hard-coded places in the source code as well such as:
./server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler.java:538:                + "/VAADIN/";
./server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/BootstrapHandler.java:698:                + "/VAADIN/"

The name and location of the VAADIN folder is also a subject matter of many places of documentation,
like
./documentation/advanced/advanced-embedding.asciidoc:92:          src="#./#VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js">
./documentation/advanced/advanced-embedding.asciidoc:243:          src="VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js">

If you manage to change it everywhere and recompile the software yourself, then congratulations. It's quite some work,
and doesn't achieve that much in return.

In a nutshell, this is something we don't support - and it's not really worth it if you think about it.

Just be proud you're using state of the art web technology : )   so there's nothing to hide when people find out!

Thanks to https://vaadin.com/web/enver/home

Answer (score 1):

No. The name of this directory is hardcoded in `VaadinServlet` so is not configurable.